# Does rowwise distribution of random values in creating a normally distributed vector variable in matrix(rnorm(.), byrow=TRUE) damage normality?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, normality-assumption, random-generation, matching

(Reprodicible example added) 150-character-limitless full question is:

Does the rowwise distribution of values in creating a normally distributed vector variable via `matrix(c(rep(rnorm(100),5)), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)` damages the normality of the component series?

In order to create a vector time series (V1,...,V5) with each component series has 100 obs and Vi~N(0,1), I wrote the following code, and then I suspected whether I made a mistake. If I distributed columnwise, definitely, it obeys the 100x5 values created via `rep(rnorm(100),5)`, and no one can object to that each Vi is N(0,1) since `rnorm` produces normally distributed values from its definition and Vi series are being set one-to-one with these `rnorm` products correspondingly.

**Question:**
But, what if I distributed these 500 random values rowwise instead of columnwise?
**1.** In that case, is the normality of the component series Vi damaged?
**2.** Or, their normality is protected but their N(0,1) property is damaged (mean and sd get affected and changes to smt N(mu, sigma2) <> N(0,1))?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(rep(rnorm(100),5)), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE))
df # class(df)=data.frame
#       V1       V2           V3          V4        V5
# 1  -0.6264538 0.1836433 -0.8356286 1.5952808  0.3295078
# ...
# 100  0.55848643 -1.27659221 -0.573265414 -1.22461261 -0.4734006
```

So, `byrow=TRUE` in the above code very dangerous or not?

**What I did:**

```
colMeans(df)
#          V1          V2          V3          V4          V5 
#  0.32352799 -0.09161396  0.20740551 -0.15577361  0.26089091
sapply(df, sd) # std deviations of each column in the dataframe
#   V1        V2        V3        V4        V5 
# 0.8957992 0.7092927 0.7919241 1.0210549 0.9314092  

set.seed(1)   # byrow=FALSE is the default for matrix
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(rep(rnorm(100),5)), ncol=5, byrow=FALSE))
colMeans(df2) # column means of each column in the dataframe
#   V1        V2        V3        V4        V5 
# 0.1088874 0.1088874 0.1088874 0.1088874 0.1088874 
sapply(df2, sd) # std deviations of each column in the dataframe
#   V1        V2        V3        V4        V5 
# 0.8981994 0.8981994 0.8981994 0.8981994 0.8981994
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matrix(c(rep(rnorm(100),5)), ncol=5, byrow=FALSE)` isn't doing what you probably think it does. It's not drawing 500 normal variates and placing them into a matrix with 5 columns. Rather, it's drawing 100 normal variates, replicating them 5 times, and filling the matrix with those replicated values. With `byrow = FALSE`, the columns are identical. With `byrow = TRUE`, every consecutive 20x5 submatrix will be identical (composed of those 100 values in order spread accross the 5 columns).

If you want to fill a 5-column matrix with 500 normal variates, 100 for each column, you need to draw 500 variates and then fill the matrix with them, as follows:

```
matrix(rnorm(5*100), ncol=5)
```

It doesn't matter whether you set `byrow` to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Every subset of values in this matrix will be normally distributed (assuming the values themselves are not used in the subsetting).

Comment: I understand my error in `rep(rnorm(100),5)`, hence I got your message via `matrix(rnorm(5*100), ncol=5)` very well. But, I could not get the 2nd part: you are saying in effect that every subset of normally distributed values are normally distributed; but why is this really so?

Comment: Because each draw from the normal distribution is independent from all others. It doesn't matter how you slice and collect the generate values (unless you use the values themselves in the slicing/collecting). The order and placement of the values in the matrix is random.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5*100, 10, 5), ncol=5)) # N=5*100; mean=10; sd=5
df # class(df)=data.frame
colMeans(df)   # The mean of each Vi column in the dataframe
#    V1          V2        V3         V4       V5 
# 10.544437  9.810960 10.148368 10.258009  9.804329

sapply(df, sd) # The sd of each Vi column in the dataframe
# If NAs had existed in the dataframe, na.rm = TRUE must have been added
#       V1        V2     V3     V4        V5
# 4.490997 4.789395 5.171328 4.958376 5.848061
```

Each subset of values in the normally distributed 5*100=500-array drawn from the population with mu=10 and sigma=5 is normally distributed (if the 500-values themselves are not used in the subsetting).

Each drawing of normally distributed sample of 5*100=500 observations that is drawn from the population with mu=10 and sigma=5 is independent from all the other 500-observation drawings from this population.

No matter how this 500-observation with N(10,5^2) is sliced, and then no matter how partitions are brought togetger and reassembled to form the sample of 500-observation is irrelevant (if the 500-value themselves are not used for slicing/collecting).

Because:

In the dim=100x5 matrix, the order and placement of the 500-observation to the cells is essentially random since the 500-observation is randomly selected from the population.

That is to say, in fact, when filling each 100-observationed column variables, we are using the population with mu=10 and sigma=5 (whose number of observations are currently unknown to us), not the 500-observation itself; in a way, we are randomly pulling 100- subobservations from the population with mu=10 and sigma=5, and we are making indirectly rnorm(100,10,5) for each column.

Therefore; the rowwise distribution of values in creating a normally distributed vector variable via `matrix(rnorm(5*100), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)` does NOT damage the normality of the component series.

P.S.: Many thanks to Noah.